# NiFi Processor taking millions of tasks then resolving

Tags: apache-nifi

I created a processor. When a PutFile fails (due to the file already existing), I want to rename a file from myfile.JPG to myfile_1.JPG to myfile_2.JPG, and so on, until PutFile succeeds. "myfile" is not expected to have an underscore anywhere in the filename until this processing occurs.

[image: nifi]

My flow looks like:
PutFile -> UpdateAttribute -> PutFile  (looped)

```
${filename:contains('_'):ifElse(   
 ${filename:substringBeforeLast('_'):append('_'):append(${filename:substringAfterLast('_'):substringBefore('.'):plus(1)}):append('.'):append(${filename:substringAfter('.')})},
 ${filename:substringBefore('.'):append('_1.'):append(${filename:substringAfter('.')})}     
)}
```

Example input filename: 2017-06-15-175053.JPG

Example output filename: 2017-06-15-175053_1.JPG

Example input filename: 2017-06-15-175053_1.JPG

Example output filename: 2017-06-15-175053_2.JPG

First I check if "_" exists in the filename (anticipated the input filename does not contain it until my Increment Name processor runs)

If "_" does exist, grab the number between "_" and ".", and increment it
If "_" does not exist, append "_.JPG" to the end.

Expected results: immediate increment of filename until the PutFile succeeds.

Actual results: after several minutes, millions of tasks executed, the file finally gets renamed to "myfile_6.JPG" and I am not sure why it is taking so many iterations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PutFile` penalizes flowfile on failure.

And by default `Penalty duration = 30sec`. It means, that next processor (UpdateAttribute) will not process this file during 30 seconds.

You could set this time to `0sec` to avoid this delay on the `Settings` tab in `Configuration` of the `PutFile` processor. So next processor will not wait to process failed file.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize a timed-based penalty was implemented via the next processor's cycles/tasks. I assumed a penalty would show no increment in tasks executed.